# Match [ABC DEF](http://google.com)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match the following string, without success.

I've this so far.

```
/\[([^\]]+)(\([^\)]+)/
```

It's the last part that won't work `(\([^\)]+)`.

In other words;

`var meta = "[ABC DEF](http://google.com)"`

- This part works.

  `meta.match(/\[([^\]]+)/) => ABC DEF`
- This doesn't work.

  `meta.match(/\[([^\]]+)(\([^\)]+)/) // => null`

This is what I want.

`["ABC DEF", "http://google.com"]`

Anyone knows why it won't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the ending `]`. Also, `)` doesn't need to be escaped in a character class. Thirdly, you could add the trailing `)`, and finally you should not put the literal `(` inside `(...)` because you don't want it to be in the matches array.

```
meta.match(/\[([^\]]+)]\(([^)]+)\)/)
                      ^  ^  ^
```

Comment: The trailing `]` should be escaped

Comment: @Reid: Should it? It works without, because there is no opening `[` so it is not ambiguous.

Comment: Ah, I see; you're correct. I'm just so used to escaping it in regexes that I didn't even consider that.